# Headphones not working in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, 10.10, sound, windows-7, headphones

I have a Gateway M-6801m laptop, my speakers work great, but when I plug my headphones, the sound is instantly muted (although the icon in the panel says that it isn't muted), I tried using different headphones and reinstalled `alsa-base` and `pulseaudio`, and that didn't fix my problem.

Here's my hardware info:

```
$ lspci | grep -i audio
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
```

I remember that when my laptop had Windows 7 installed, the headphones didn't work unless I installed a specific driver from Gateway's site.
Also, when I run SunOS 11 from the live cd, my headphones work without any need to hack/change/tweak, I tried to run Ubuntu 12.04 and 10.10 from the live cd, and no luck, it didn't work.

Here's a more detailed file with my system information:
http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=233963a7a2edc8b659b21396137747b291d1ff00