# Sound issues after trying everything

Tags: 12.10, sound, headphones, speakers

I cannot get my sound working properly, no matter what I do, there's always some problem. It's very annoying as it's the only thing preventing me from making Ubuntu my main OS.

<del>At the moment my sound always plays through both my speakers and my headphones regardless except the sound through the headphones is crackly. It is also a bit quiet even though everything is maxed.</del>

I've managed to *improve* the situation to a point where the sound out of my speakers is perfect but I have none at all from my headphones. I do have two connectors listed in the sound settings but regardless of which one is selected it always plays through the speakers.

I *think* this might have something to do with the fact that my speakers are plugging into the front of my computer, typically the headphone jack, and my headphones are plugging into the back but when I try disconnecting the speakers from the front there is still no sound from the headphones.

I fixed the speaker sound by going through the sound settings and making sure they were all set to 100% then rebooting.

Things I have tried:

- Maxing everything and unmuting everything in alsamixer
- Uninstalling PulseAudio
- Making GStreamer use the only ALSA via GStreamer-properties. This
  worked with the sound test button including independent sound between headphones and speakers but when I reset the computer it no longer worked. So I tried setting it manually in `gconf-editor` which didn't work either.
- Reinstalling alsa and PulseAudio
- Setting the model in `etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` to 6stack and 6stack-dig neither worked.
- Upgrading to 12.10

Here's some command output to help you diagnose my problem.

---

`aplay -l`

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: AD198x Analog [AD198x Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 1: AD198x Digital [AD198x Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 2: AD198x Headphone [AD198x Headphone]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

---

`sudo lshw -C sound`

```
  *-multimedia            
       description: Audio device
       product: 82801JI (ICH10 Family) HD Audio Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1b
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:70 memory:f7ff8000-f7ffbfff
```

---

`cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep "Codec"`

```
Codec: Analog Devices AD1989B
```

---

`cat /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

```
# autoloader aliases
install sound-slot-0 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-0
install sound-slot-1 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-1
install sound-slot-2 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-2
install sound-slot-3 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-3
install sound-slot-4 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-4
install sound-slot-5 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-5
install sound-slot-6 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-6
install sound-slot-7 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-7

# Cause optional modules to be loaded above generic modules
install snd /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }
#
# Workaround at bug #499695 (reverted in Ubuntu see LP #319505)
install snd-pcm /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; }
install snd-mixer /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-mixer $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-mixer-oss ; : ; }
install snd-seq /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-seq $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-oss ; : ; }
#
install snd-rawmidi /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-rawmidi $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; : ; }
# Cause optional modules to be loaded above sound card driver modules
install snd-emu10k1 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-emu10k1 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-emu10k1-synth ; }
install snd-via82xx /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-via82xx $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }

# Load saa7134-alsa instead of saa7134 (which gets dragged in by it anyway)
install saa7134 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install saa7134 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist saa7134-alsa ; : ; }
# Prevent abnormal drivers from grabbing index 0
options bt87x index=-2
options cx88_alsa index=-2
options saa7134-alsa index=-2
options snd-atiixp-modem index=-2
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
options snd-via82xx-modem index=-2
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-usb-caiaq index=-2
options snd-usb-ua101 index=-2
options snd-usb-us122l index=-2
options snd-usb-usx2y index=-2
# Ubuntu #62691, enable MPU for snd-cmipci
options snd-cmipci mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
# Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard
options snd-pcsp index=-2
# Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-hda-intel model=6stack
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, you can try the answers [in this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165789/headphones-not-working-in-ubuntu-12-04).
I didn't have any problem with the speakers, but with the headphones. I resolved my problem by following the steps provided [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS).

I hope this will solve your problem.