# Headphones and ubuntu 12.04 (again)

Tags: 12.04, sound, headphones

As the title says. The description is [classical](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165789/headphones-not-working-in-ubuntu-12-04?lq=1): the internal speaker works but plugging in headphones makes it go silent. I did try to install [DKMS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS) but it still doesn't work.

```
lspci | grep -i audio
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Panther Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
```

and

```
cat /proc/asound/card0/codec* | grep Codec
Codec: Realtek ALC269VC
Codec: Intel PantherPoint HDMI
```

I sort of suspect it has something to do with setting the options in

```
 analog-output-headphones.conf
```

or maybe a kernel update from today because yesterday the headphones were working :(

## edit:

following MarkPaskal's suggestion i get this (when the  headphones are plugged in):

[image: e.g. no more 'headphone option']

Comment: Click the volume indicator and click 'Sound Settings' and make sure the headphones are selected like in this picture:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/0bKsi.png

Comment: @MarkPaskal: that option has disappeared: see edit

Comment: you should add how you solved this as an answer and accept it so it's easier to fix for the next person. comments can be deleted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[that](https://askubuntu.com/a/185357/2413) answer did it for me.....

So basically, you type:

```
ctrl-alt-t
```

to fire up a terminal

```
sudo apt-get autoremove pulseaudio

sudo apt-get install gnome-alsamixer
```

you reboot and it will work. The sound 
was too weak and a bit metallic initially 
but i could fix that by typing

```
alsamixer
```

in a terminal and tuning things from there...
(i had tried to tune things with alsamixer before 
rm-ing pulseaudio but it was not working)